# Bash comparing values

Tags: bash, file, comparison

I'm getting the size of a file from a remote webserver and saving the results to a var called `remote`  I get this using:

```
remote=`curl -sI $FILE | grep -i Length | awk '/Content/{print $(NF-0)}'`
```

Once I've downloaded the file I'm getting the local files size with:

```
local=`stat --print="%s" $file`
```

If I echo remote and local they contain the same value.

I'm trying to run an if statement for this

```
if [ "$local" -ne "$remote" ]; then
```

But it always shows the error message, and never advises they match.

Can someone advise what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What is output of `declare -p local remote`

Comment: This may not be the source of your problem, but `local` is a reserved word for defining local variables within a function.

Comment: You might have a carriage return at the end of your `curl` output. Check with `printf '%q\n' "$remote"` if there's a `\r`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`curl`'s output uses the network format for text, meaning that lines are terminated by a carriage return followed by linefeed; unix tools (like the shell) expect lines to end with just linefeed, so they treat the CR as part of the content of the line, and often get confused. In this case, what's happening is that the `remote` variable is getting the content length *and* a CR, which isn't valid in a numeric expression, hence errors. There are many ways to strip the CR, but in this case it's probably easiest to have `awk` do it along with the field extraction:

```
remote=$(curl -sI "$remotefile" | grep -i Length | awk '/Content/{sub("\r","",$NF); print $NF}')
```

BTW, I also took the liberty of replacing backticks with `$( )` -- this is easier to read, and doesn't have some oddities with escapes that backticks have, so it's the preferred syntax for capturing command output. Oh, and `(NF-0)` is equivalent to just `NF`, so I simplified that. As @Jason pointed out in a comment, it's safest to use lower- or mixed-case for variable names, and put double-quotes around references to them, so I did that by changing `$FILE` to `"$remotefile"`. You should do the same with the local filename variable.

You could also drop the `grep` command and have `awk` search for `/^Content-Length:/` to simplify it even further.

Comment: Perfect thanks this has helped a lot and has resolved my issue.